# Block IE but keep some reserved links

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I blocked **Internet Explorer** (IE 6~9) via Apache `.htaccess`, so all links will be blocked if the agent equivalent to **Internet Explorer**, Now I want to ask that is it possible to ignore some reserved links?

here is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-9]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !ie 
RewriteRule .* /ie [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put another `RewriteCond` to ignore certain URIs from this block. See an example below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-9]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1899&auth=user(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ie|ignore1|ignore2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ie [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I defined a links with get parameters in the above code? e.g `http://mywebsite.com/dl/?id=1899&auth=user`

Comment: That requires another `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` e.g. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1899[&|$) [NC]`

Comment: I'm sorry but how about this `http://mywebsite.com/dl/test.zip`? where `test.zip` is a simple `RewriteRule`.